# How to read image in OpenCV-3.2 java using Eclips

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am using OpenCV-3.2 in Eclips. I want to to read an image but it is showing error in `import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;` this line what I do?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what do u mean read